# Mongodb Compass: date quesry returns noting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I use Mongodb Atlas to query data from collestion. Data like this

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65253ba83d0450a7bcf2e4ad"
  },
  "name": "Andrea Le",
  "email": "andrea_le@fake-mail.com",
  "version": 5,
  "scores": [
    85,
    95,
    75
  ],
  "dateCreated": {
    "$date": "2003-03-26T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

And my query for date field is

```
{ dateCreated: { $gt: Date('2000-06-22') } }
```

This is a simple example from MongoDB documentation. But this query returns nothing. What is a problem?

Comment: Change 'Date' to 'new Date'. So, it should look like this: $gt: new Date("2000-06-22"). You can see the output here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/k6ida57xrVA , just run it

Comment: Thank, it works!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change

```
{ dateCreated: { $gt: Date('2000-06-22') } }
```

to

```
{ dateCreated: { $gt: new Date('2000-06-22') } }
```

and get corrent result. Thank 
[Onur Doğan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19724868/onur-do%c4%9fan)!